# How to set enumerable property for Babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to use module compiled with Babel in TypeScript project. But I've got error with static properties and methods.

This is TypeScript helper for `extends`. As you can see it uses `for..in`.

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
```

Is there any way to set `enumerable` for static properties/methods for Babel?

[image]

Comment: You could manually `Object.defineProperty(XmlObject, 'LoadXml', {enumerable: true})`. The ES6 spec dictates these are non-enumerable.

Comment: You say you've got an error, but not what the error is. Static methods are not enumerable per the ES6 spec (see 21.b. under [14.5.14 Runtime Semantics: ClassDefinitionEvaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation)). Your screenshot shows that `Test.LoadXml()` correctly calls `XmlObject.LoadXml` (it logs "`Success`"). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Jordan I don't have result on Test.LoadXml(). This is error, cause it must have this function

Comment: Seems to me that the TypeScript helper should be fixed instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **loose** options in the [ES2015 classes transform](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-classes/) plugin, the default value is `false`. You can set this value to `true` like this

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-es2015-classes", {
      "loose": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

With this setting , methods will be defined on class prototype object . But this will cause some other problems.

```
class Foo {
  set bar() {
    throw new Error("foo!");
  }
}
class Bar extends Foo {
  bar() {
    // will throw an error when this method is defined
  }
}
```

Please see the [document](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-classes/) for more details.